# What do i use with LINQ in order to READ database instead of SqlDataReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to use LINQ for the first time and don't understand how to read through the database. I'm sure I am doing something completely stupid and just need a little guidance.

```
year = year.Where(x => x.statementYear == response[i]).ToList();

SqlDataReader reader;

while (reader.Read())
{

}
```

Edited question with more info:

This is what I have been trying to get to work.. I don't think I need the `con.open()` either if I am using the using statement right?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(".."))
{
    List<string> paths = new List<string>();

    // Open Connection
    con.Open();

    if (response != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                using (var db = new db())
                {
                    List<ClientStatement_Inventory> years = new List<ClientStatement_Inventory>();

                    years = years.Where(x => x.statementYear == response[i]).ToList();

                    foreach (var year in years)
                    {
                        paths.Add(year.statementPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Linq, there's no use or point in using `SqlDataReader`....

You really didn't show much to go on - but basically, with Linq, you should have a `DbContext` (that's your "connection" to the database), and that `DbContext` should contain any number of `DbSet` - basically representing the tables in your database. You select from these `DbSet`'s and then you get back a `List<Entity>` which you just iterate over.

Something along the lines of:

```
-- select your customers matching a certain criteria
var customers = NorthwindDbContext.Customers.Where(x => x.statementYear == response[i]).ToList();

-- iterate over your customers
foreach (Customer c in customers)
{
     // do whatever with your "Customer" here
}
```

**UPDATE:**

from your updated question - all you really need is:

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>();

using (var db = new FMBDBPRDEntities1())
{
    List<ClientStatement_Inventory> years = new List<ClientStatement_Inventory>();

    years = years.Where(x => x.statementYear == response[i]).ToList();

    foreach (var year in years)
    {
        paths.Add(year.statementPath);
    }
}
```

That opens the context to access the database, reads some data into a list, iterates over the elements in the list - done. Everything else is useless and can be just deleted.

And you could write this a lot simpler, too:

```
using (var db = new FMBDBPRDEntities1())
{
    List<string> paths = years.Where(x => x.statementYear == response[i])
                              .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();
}
```

**UPDATE #2**: if your `response` is a collection of values (I'm *assuming* those would be `int` values), and you need to iterate over it - try something like this:

```
if (response != null)
{
    List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();

    using (var db = new FMBDBPRDEntities1())
    {
        foreach (int aYear in response)
        {
            List<string> paths = years.Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                                      .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();

            allPaths.AddRange(paths);
        }
    }

    return allPaths; // or do whatever with your total results
}
```

**UPDATE #3**: just wondering - it seems you never really access the `DbContext` at all ..... I'm just *guessing* here - but something along the lines of:

```
if (response != null)
{
    List<string> allPaths = new List<string>();

    using (var db = new FMBDBPRDEntities1())
    {
        foreach (int aYear in response)
        {
            // access a DbSet from your DbContext here! 
            // To actually fetch data from the database.....
            List<string> paths = db.ClientStatement_Inventory
                                   .Where(x => x.statementYear == aYear)
                                   .Select(y => y.statementPath).ToList();

            allPaths.AddRange(paths);
        }
    }

    return allPaths; // or do whatever with your total results
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with a little more code. With what I am trying it never fully runs through the foreach statement. It gives me this error: " data not available. see the locals window for available intellitrace data "

Comment: @New_Coder: updated my response with showing you what you really need....

Comment: Thank you for your update.. But I still need a for loop to iterate through the response so that I can get the index of response right?

Comment: @New_Coder: it's quite unclear from your code posted what that `response` really is - but if it's a collection, and you need to iterate over it - then yes, you need a loop - but no `SqlDataReader` or any of that, really ...

Comment: Thats weird, its still not entering my foreach statement

Comment: @New_Coder: added an update #2 to illustrate how to loop over the "results" (whatever that may be) and call your LINQ statement multiple times and assemble the complete results.

Comment: I think its my Linq method. I am trying to change this sql command : "select statementPath from ClientStatement_Inventory where statementYear = '" + response[i] + "';", con))    To  a Linq query method but don't think im doing it right. I probably need to open a new question.

Comment: its still not putting any paths into the list. Is what I am getting back is an array of strings. I changed your foreach to string and it still isn't grabbing it. When I used my SqlCommand it worked and would grab what I needed. super weird.

Comment: @New_Coder: well - somehow it seems you're never really selecting from the  `dbContext` at all - see my update #3 ....

Comment: You are amazing!!!! Thank you so much for the help now I just gotta figure out how to download those files in my controller. Thank you for all the help!